# Sleep command in PHP returns non zero

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have a script, that is run as a part of my module in Drupal.
In this module, I use cURL functions to request html page from a remote website, then I parse the html content and write it to my database.
I wanted to have a delay between every request that I do to the remote server, hence I added `sleep()` in my PHP script.

```
function get_me_data()
{
  for( 15 iterations)
  {
    $html  =  file_get_contents($search_url);
    //parse html contents
    $delay  = mt_rand($interval1,$interval2); // interval1 = 0 , interval2=30
    $retval = sleep($delay);
  }
}
```

1. function `get_me_data()` is initiated by cron job(hook_cron implemented in .module file).
2. I have also tried to flush streams before the usage of sleep command.
   used `flush(); ob_flush();fflush(filepointer); ob_implicit_flush(true)`

It so happens that after 4-5 iterations, `sleep()` command returns NON ZERO value.
the script aborts in the next iteration when `sleep()` is called

Let me know, if I am overlooking any aspect of `sleep()` here.
I am using, PHP version 5.3 & Drupal 6

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php can return non zero values.

> If the call was interrupted by a signal, sleep() returns a non-zero value. On Windows, this value will always be 192 (the value of the WAIT_IO_COMPLETION constant within the Windows API). On other platforms, the return value will be the number of seconds left to sleep.

A comment in the sleep uses [time_sleep_until()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php) because it doesn't get interrupted.

Comment: thanks for the input.I have used time_sleep_until() too. one strange thing i notice here is, neither sleep() nor time_sleep_until() fails when i run these scripts on my drupal localhost installation.

Comment: I have validated the php script on my server with time_sleep_until() too. After two iterations, I see a debug statement just before the function call and then there are no debug statements.

Comment: @rachel what OS are you running on localhost/server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have Windows 7 on my localhost and I have my website running on my VPS hosting hosted on Linux(not sure about the version though). Looks like the error that I was encountering was because on my server the mysql configuration was set to timeout after 50 seconds.

Comment: @rachel glad you found the cause, might be worth answering the question yourself and marking it as the accepted answer to help anyone having a similar issue.